# How to mock arguments passed into Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mocking

**Update**

The injection of `LdapService` is not working as expected. Spring is creating new instances, but the object does not take part in the usual DI lifecycle of a managed bean. For example, a `@PostConstruct` method or `@Value` annotations in `LdapService` do net get called/injected. So I assume that Spring is just creating instances in terms of a model bean but not in the sense of a managed bean.

Thus, the whole question about mocking of this object is obsolete.

*End of Update*

How can I mock a service that is passed as an argument to a Spring MVC Controller?

Service that should be mocked. It is with scope "prototype" which is important in my scenario:

```
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class LdapService {
    ...
}
```

Spring MVC Controller:

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {
    @GetMapping("/something")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> doSomething(
            @Valid @RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO,
            @Autowired LdapService ldapService) {
        ldapService.invokeSomeMethod(someDTO.getName());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(PasswordController.class)
public class SomeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void doSomeTest() throws Exception {
        // In the following call, a mocked LdapService shall be used!
        mockMvc.perform(get("/something"));
```

How can I mock the LdapService in this example?

Comment: why don't you call the method doSomething(...) using your mock?

Comment: Good question. Because the real code contains another parameter - a DTO and I would like to test the URI and parameter validation. I will update my example code.